# retrofit Throwing new exception 'length=1188; index=1366' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

version retrofit 2.0，Android studio 3.6.3

```
Throwing new exception 'length=1188; index=1366' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

When I input `phoneNum`, and call http:

```
/**
 * 手机号发送验证码
 */
@JvmStatic
fun sendSms(phoneNum: String, observer: ApiBaseObserver<ZmServerBean<String>>) {
    apiZmServiceParam.sendSms(phoneNum)
            .compose(RxBiz.transformMain())
            .subscribe(observer)
}
```

only find on android os 7.0